# Centralize the Certificate Authority in puppet server version 4

Tags: puppet

I am trying to create multiple puppet master servers with a central certificate authority using the following link:
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3/scaling_multiple_masters.html#option-1-direct-agent-nodes-to-the-ca-master
But this doc is according to puppet version 3, and with puppet 4 there is puppet server which runs over a JVM and jetty serving the requests. As in the above doc apache forwards all certificate URI's to central server, How do I create the same architecture with puppet 4.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's only possible with Enterprise Puppet.
I think, than with open source one you can continue to use Apache/Nginx and proxy requests to CA or configure webserver.conf and user ca_server on all agents puppet.conf. I'm not sure what can be done with CRL revocation.
With Puppet 3.8 we use the following scheme and I think it should work with new puppetserver (it's kinda crazy though):

1. When certificate being cleaned on CA by someone we catch inotify
   event with incron daemon.
2. incron runs curl with GET request to all puppet master

   ```
   pwgen -1 > /tmp/crl
   curl --data-binary '@/tmp/crl' http://puppetmaster:8887/crl
   ```
3. In nginx config on master we have the following:

   ```
   server {
       listen 8887;
       server_name puppetmaster.net;
       root /var/www;
       location /crl {

           limit_except POST          { deny all; }

           client_body_temp_path      /srv/puppet/crl/;
           client_body_in_file_only   on;
           client_body_buffer_size    128K;
           client_max_body_size       128K;

           proxy_pass_request_headers on;
           proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file;
           proxy_set_body             off;
           proxy_redirect             off;
           proxy_pass                 http://localhost:8888;
       }
   }
   server {
       listen localhost:8888;
       server_name localhost;
       root /var/www;
   }
   ```
4. So we saving request in a file and have one more incron daemon on master to catch this and run one more request to CA and download CRL via CA API 
   (see puppet doc). Reload httpd after. We do it as following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   PID='/tmp/crlpid'
   if [[ -f $PID ]]; then
       exit
   else
       touch $PID
   fi

   function check {
       rm -f /srv/puppet/crl/*
       sleep 10
       COUNT=$(ls -1 /srv/puppet/crl | wc -l)
       if [[ $COUNT > 0 ]]; then
           check
       else
           return 0
       fi
   }

   if check; then
       STATUS='NOTSET'

       SSLDIR=`puppet config print ssldir`
       CERTNAME=`hostname -f`

       ENV=`puppet config print environment`
       URL="https://puppetca:8140/${ENV}/certificate_revocation_list/ca"

       CRT=`puppet config print cacert`
       CRL=`puppet config print cacrl`
       TMPCRL="/tmp/puppet_ca_crlpem.tmp"

       curl --output "${TMPCRL}" \
           --cacert "${SSLDIR}/certs/ca.pem" \
           --cert "${SSLDIR}/certs/${CERTNAME}.pem" \
           --key "${SSLDIR}/private_keys/${CERTNAME}.pem" \
           -H "Accept: s" "${URL}"

       openssl crl -text -in "${TMPCRL}" -CAfile "${CRT}" -noout > /dev/null 2>&1 && STATUS='VALID'

       if [[ "${STATUS}" == "VALID" ]]; then
           mv -f "${TMPCRL}" "${CRL}"
           chown puppet:puppet "${CRL}"
           systemctl reload httpd.service
       fi
       rm -f $PID
   fi
   ```